# Create json file with annotation for entity from text file and also append the startIndex and endIndex into the dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, annotations

I would like to append the startIndex and endIndex into the "check". Can anyone please help me?

Example,

I have startIndex and endIndex in dictionary form like this:

```
"startIndex":3, "endIndex":5
```

And

I wanted to append it into the "check" in the text to become something like this.

```
"check": [{"startIndex":3, "endIndex":5}]
```

If possible, I wish to add another pair of key:value("gender":"M") into this "check" to become:

```
"check": [{"gender":"M", "startIndex":3, "endIndex":5}]
```

My code:

My input for the start and end index are:

```
{'startIndex': 6, 'endIndex': 10}
{'startIndex': 31, 'endIndex': 35}
{'startIndex': 15, 'endIndex': 19}
{'startIndex': 11, 'endIndex': 15}
{'startIndex': 22, 'endIndex': 26}
{'startIndex': 6, 'endIndex': 10}
{'startIndex': 4, 'endIndex': 8}
{'startIndex': 5, 'endIndex': 9}
{'startIndex': 24, 'endIndex': 28}
{'startIndex': 32, 'endIndex': 36}
{'startIndex': 12, 'endIndex': 16}
{'startIndex': 15, 'endIndex': 19}
{'startIndex': 13, 'endIndex': 17}
{'startIndex': 24, 'endIndex': 28}
{'startIndex': 23, 'endIndex': 27}
{'startIndex': 19, 'endIndex': 23}
{'startIndex': 20, 'endIndex': 24}
{'startIndex': 24, 'endIndex': 28}
{'startIndex': 16, 'endIndex': 20}
{'startIndex': 10, 'endIndex': 14}
{'startIndex': 4, 'endIndex': 8}
{'startIndex': 28, 'endIndex': 32}
{'startIndex': 27, 'endIndex': 31}
{'startIndex': 25, 'endIndex': 29}
{'startIndex': 21, 'endIndex': 25}
{'startIndex': 3, 'endIndex': 7}
{'startIndex': 20, 'endIndex': 24}
{'startIndex': 25, 'endIndex': 29}
{'startIndex': 9, 'endIndex': 13}


TestSmart = [{"text": "I am smart boy", "name": "null", "original": null, "location": [], "person": [], "sound": "", "check": [], "id": 0}, {"text": "I am so smart last time", "name": "null", "original": null, "location": [], "person": [], "sound": "", "check": [], "id": 1}, {"text": "They always call me smart boy", "name": "null", "original": null, "location": [], "person": [], "sound": "", "check": [], "id": 2}]

import json
import re

with open("TestSmart.txt", "r") as f:
    test = f.read().splitlines()

lemmas = []
sea= []
for x in test:
    for m in re.finditer("smart",x):
        start=m.start()
        end=m.end()
        se = dict([("startIndex", start), ("endIndex", end)] )
        sea.append(se)


i = 0 
null = None 
for x in test:
    text = dict([("text",x), ("name",null), ("originalText",null), ("location",[]), ("person",[]), 
                 ("sound", ""), ("check",[]), ("id",i)])
    lemmas.append(text)
    i+=1


new = []
for x in text:
    for se in sea:
        if len(text["check"]) == 0 or len(text["check"]) >= 1:
            text["check"].append(se)



print(lemmas)      

with open("new.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:  
    json.dump(lemmas, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I wish it to become like this:(by looping and inserting my startIndex and endIndex into the list when "smart" appears in the sentence and if "smart" does not appear then it should not append into "check" and "check" will remain as empty list".

```
[{"text": "I am smart boy", "name": "null", "original": null, "location": [], "person": [], "sound": "", "check": [{"gender":"M", "startIndex":3, "endIndex":4}], "id": 0}, {"text": "I am so smart last time", "name": "null", "original": null, "location": [], "person": [], "sound": "", "check": [{"gender":"M", "startIndex":10, "endIndex":12}], "id": 1}, {"text": "They always call me smart boy", "name": "null", "original": null, "location": [], "person": [], "sound": "", "check": [{"gender":"M", "startIndex":5, "endIndex":7}], "id": 2}]
```

Comment: Is `gender` always going to be `M` or will that value come from the `TestSmart.txt`? Do you have some sample input?

Comment: The "gender" input is just an input I wish to include. It can be any input or maybe just an empty list is ok too.

Comment: OK. Is the script working correctly apart from your wanting `check` to be amended? There are some lines that are a little confusing (e.g. `if len(text["check"]) == 0 or len(text["check"]) >= 1:`) but perhaps they make sense with the appropriate input.

Comment: @i alarmed alien Yes, so far is only this not working: 

new = []
for x in text:
    for se in sea:
        if len(text["check"]) == 0 or len(text["check"]) >= 1:
            text["check"].append(se)

this part might need some changes I guess. But I do not know from where to check.

Comment: If you upload a couple of lines of sample input and what you want the output to look like, we can solve all the issues in one go.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I have uploaded another example input and also my preferred output. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything in one pass through the file and save yourself having to correlate the data in `sea` with the line from the text file.

It's a lot quicker (IMO) to create a dictionary using this shorthand (and it looks like JSON!):

```
d = { "key": "value", "key2": "value2" }
```

rather than

```
d = dict([ ("key", "value") ], [ ("key2", "value2") ])
```

Here's how you could redo your script:

```
lemmas = []
i = 0 
null = None 

for x in test:
    # find the position of 'smart' in the text, and store it in the list `checks`
    # checks will be empty if the word 'smart' does not appear in the line
    checks = []
    for m in re.finditer("smart",x):
        # creating a dict and append it to the list in one step
        checks.append( { "startIndex": m.start(), "endIndex": m.end(), "Gender": 'M' } )

    # create a dict and append the data for this line to `lemmas`:
    lemmas.append( { "text": x, "name": null, "originalText": null, "location": [], "person": [], 
              "sound": "", "check": checks, "id": i } )

    i+=1

print(lemmas)
```

...and then dump it out as JSON.

I hope that what I've done is clear -- if not, please ask.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. This is what I wanted it to be.